# merging two files with write and read in C

Tags: c

I would like to merge two files using `open` and file descriptor. Moreover I would like to separate the content of the first file with `-` before writing the the content of the second file.

I did the following :

```
void merge (char* fileName, char *fileName1) {
    int fd = open(fileName, O_RDWR);
    char c;
    while (read(fd, c, 1) > 0) {//going at the end of the first file
    }

    char next[] = "\n";
    char charc[] = "-";
    
    write (fd, next, strlen(next));

    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        if (write (fd, charc, strlen(charc)) == -1) {
            perror("error :  ");
        }
    }
    
    write (fd, next, strlen(next));
    
    int fd1 = open(fileName1, O_RDWR);
    while(read(fd1, &c, 1) > 0) {
        write(fd, &c, sizeof(c));
    }
    
    close(fd1);
    close(fd);
}
```

Is there a better way to write this code ? Moreover I have a little problem even if it works it seems like I don't have the right to read the new file. For example if I do `cat newFile` I have a permission denied.

Comment: At least `strlen(char)` should be changed to some other thing.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes mb I meant strlen(charc)

Comment: `going at the end of the first file` just use `O_APPEND`

Comment: "even if it works": you mean you don't know if it works or not?

Comment: @ScottHunter No it does work because I tried it. I am just looking for improvement.

Comment: `while (read(fd, c, 1) > 0) {}` is a long way to go to the end of the file, look at `fseek` ... out of the fact this is useless

Comment: @bruno [`lseek()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html) is used with POSIX `open()`.  `fseek()` is standard C and used with `fopen()`.  Nevermind the missing `&` on `c` in the posted code causing undefined behavior....

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes I know, this is part of the "long way" (sorry I was not be clear enough), also the use of literal string when a char is enough, to continue even an error occurred when `write` etc

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to write this code ?

- You are not handling errors of all calls. All of syscalls `open`, `write`, `read` and `close` return `-1` on error and set errno and may do that at any time. `EINTR` could be handled.
- `going at the end of the first file` `open` has `O_APPEND` flag mode that is used for appending data.
- Copying *one character* at a time is very not optimal. With glibc standard library you could use [`BUFSIZ`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html) bytes at a time that is chosen for fast I/O output. You could make a copy of a big chunk size at a time that is a power of 2, like 2048 or 4096.
- There is little reason to use file descriptors here - prefer to use standard `FILE *` handling, which would make your code portable and also buffer the data for faster I/O.
- If you wish to create the file use `O_CREAT` and add the third argument to `open` that is the mask of permissions of new file.
- On linux there is [splice(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) system call that can be used to append data on kernel side for maximum efficiency.